# Word boundary not working for amount in dollars (REgex)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex which will match amount in $.

```
 (\-?\$\-?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|usd\-?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*\-?usd|[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*\$)
```

Currently its matching for **$250**, **USD250** etc, it should not match the **$250** in **$250abchhh**.

So, I tried word boundary, but it didn't fix the issue as well, how can I fix this issue?

matching cases are

```
 $456 
 $45.6
 $.5
 $-45
 -$45
 usd-456
 usd46
 usd4.6
 usd.46
 1$
 1.5$
 .5$
 -.5$
 5usd
 456usd
```

it should not match

```
  455$abc
  abc$123
  abcuds1
  jhb$5665usdjnjnb
  $usd1555
  usd$768
  $566usd
  $5788usdbjhj
```

Comment: But your regex has no problems you are talking about. Look here:https://regex101.com/r/rAJLc0/6. You have problems when you have both $ and usd and in work with decimal dot. What exactly do you want to solve? "but it only matches it with a separate amount." - the phrase has no sense, sorry.

Comment: removed that sentence

Comment: It is different question than the supposed duplicate. That another one asks how to read dollar sums more simply. This one asks how to cut off the unwanted parts of line.

Answer (score 0):

You should also write a correct regex for a decimal. And use ^$ for start and end of line.

```
^\s*(?:(?:(?:-?(?:usd|\$)|(?:usd|\$)-)(?:(?:0|[1-9]\d*)?(?:\.\d+)?(?<=\d)))|(?:-?(?:(?:0|[1-9]\d*)?(?:\.\d+)?(?<=\d))(?:usd|\$)))\s*$
```

Look [here](https://regex101.com/r/rAJLc0/8) at the test results.